# read txt file line by line and update variable on each line

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api

I am trying to read a txt file line by line using fetch()

here is what I have:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8888/foo.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then((data) => {
  var player = GetPlayer();
  player.SetVar("phrase",data);
  })
```

this code is reading the entire txt file at once and showing it on the *"phrase"* variable correctly.

But I want something like:
read line 1 -> show line 1 on the variable
read line 2 -> show line 2 on the variable
read line 3 -> show line 3 on the variable
...

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What does _"show line x on the variable"_ mean?

Comment: it means that, let's say, the txt file content on line 1 the word "cat" on the next line "dog" and on line 3 "parrot" then I want to show on the variable: cat and then pressing for instance a button, the variable has to show the word dog and then the word parrot. does that make sense?

Comment: If you want to use line-by-line reading for performance reasons, don't bother, as the whole thing is already loaded in memory in case of JavaScript. But for functionality reason, you can just do a `split(\n)` which gives you an array with every line as a member

Comment: @aghArdeshir I am already adding the `split(\n)` but stills giving me the whole text in the file:

`var lines = data.split('\n');
for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
var player = GetPlayer();
player.SetVar("phrase", data);`

Comment: @efe Well, in that case there is probably some other line-endings are used other than you expect. maybe `\r` `\r\n`, maybe some custom code concatenates all strings together. you can console.log your `data` and using `charCodeAt`, check what character exists between the words.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use some String methods. You can use a .split() method with `\n` as the regex which will split your data into an array.

Example:

Let's suppose a text file at localhost:6060/foo.txt have the following content:

Format - `username:password`

```
Peter:NoLol1231@
Maffe:xDOkLmao
Loe:OOPSOkay
John:OhXDAlright
```

We can access the data in a proper way like this,

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
async function getData() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       let result = (await (await fetch("http://localhost:6060/foo.txt")).text()).split('\n');
       let finalres = result.map((x) => ({[x.split(':')[0]]: x.split(':')[1]}));
       resolve(finalres)
   });
}

getData((d) => {
   console.log(d["Peter"]); // Will print his password now!
});
```

Comment: you're right but maybe show an example based on his sample code

Comment: an example it would be great, I understand that the split() should go between the first and the second  .then ?

Comment: @daysling I've modified the code adding: 
var textByLine = data.split("\n");
before
var player = GetPlayer();
but still reading the whole document at once

Comment: @efe, You're not returning the value from .text() you shall should make it return the .text(), I mean `.then(response => response.text())....` should be changed into `  .then(response => return response.text())....`

Comment: @daysling thanks heaps for your answer but I should split the lines in a non async context. is that possible?